# after slideToggle in IE8 on Windows XP margin disappears

Tags: jquery, css, windows-xp, margin, slidetoggle

Issue is demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hNvzx/1/)

After two clicks on "Click me", margin of #content2 disappears. It only happens in IE8 on Windows XP. The simplest solution is to replace top margin of #content 2 with a `<div style="height:30px">&nbsp;</div>`. But that's not acceptable since there are many sliding divs. A CSS solution is acceptable!

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `overflow: hidden`

```
#content {
    position:relative;
/*  overflow:hidden; */
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#432234;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hNvzx/7/

Comment: It does not work. I doubt that you've tried it on IE8 on Win XP.

Comment: What is your version of IE8? My is 8.6001.18702 on Win XP SP3

Comment: Exactly the same version :|